# Getting web application production ready (angularjs/nodejs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dev-to-production

My web application consists of angularjs on front end side and nodejs server listening to client requests. This is my folder structure:[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MBW6.png)

UX contains client side code and IT contains server side code. I am using gulp to watch over development changes and for packaging (you can see the dist folder in UX). I use two terminals to launch this web application locally. From one terminal, I use `gulp serve` (UX folder) to start a static UI server which monitors the changes as I make to UI and reflect back the changes on the browser immediately. From the second terminal, I start a `node server2.js` server.

The UX/src/app folder has a config file where I specify server ip address and app.js uses this info to connect to server (currently).

Now, I want to deploy this app over cloud. On the cloud, I have to specify a `node it/server2.js` as a starting point in its config file. Hence, I want the corresponding web link should point to index.html in UX/src/app folder.

Hence, I need some advice on how to integrate my client side app.js file in the server2.js file on server side.

I am an amateur.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to my server2.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static("ux/dist/"));

app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Currently, it is invoking index.html page from UX folder. But, I am not sure whether I have done it the ideal way. Need help on this.